# Django 1.9 :не показывает изображения

Tags: django, изображения

Cоздал модель, все поля из модели отображаются, кроме изображения
Сервер фото отдает, но в браузере не показывает, запускаю другие проекты, все работает!
что не так?

upd.не отражает вообще изображений которые локально находятся на компьютере, только по ссылке с инета

[image: браузер]

models.py

```
class Trademark(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
tm1 = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('page.urls')),
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
}),] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

page.html

```
<img src="{{trademark.tm1.url}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
}),
```

сделайте как написано в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

И да, у вас ссылка на `media` дублируется. Перепишите и статику через `static`, и `media` через функцию `static` Остальное навскидку верно

Comment: изменил как написано в документации(почистил куки и кэш, удалил папку медиа, сделал миграцию), никакого эффекта!
 
если правильно понял, то вы говорите изменить ссылки в settings.py???
вот что выдает:
 raise ImproperlyConfigured("The MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL settings must have different values

Comment: @SikoraYaroslav в urls у вас ```url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$'``` и ```static(settings.MEDIA_URL, ``` - это одна и та же ссылка, удалите первую

Comment: правильно?    
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('page.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: @SikoraYaroslav Да

Answer (score 0):

проблема в page.urls.py некоректно прописан адрес